# Blender adding image / texture on object does not show up in .obj document

Tags: image, textures, blender, texturing

I've watched some tutorials on how to add images to an object in blender. There are different ways to do it but I choose to do it as the following: with UV image editor and making a material and after that a texture for the image.

This is how it looks in blender as rendered, the front and back view: [image: blender rendered front]
[image: blender rendered back]

I need this blender project to be exported to a .obj file so I can use it for an AR project in ENTiTi, but no matter what I Do, the rectangle will be empty when exported to .obj

[image: object exported]

Material and texture preview:
[image: preview1]
[image: preview2]

Can you guys please help me because I can't find a solution on google or youtube. **I made a **google drive directory** with the blender file, .obj file and the images: 
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WdspdKiK28vTmJVepi_FWb4Avs1pZOw5?usp=sharing**

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Hmm: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123520

Answer (score 1):

.obj format do not export the texture applied to the model, it should export the materials and texture in an .mtl file. You would need to apply the .mtl file to your .obj inside your development environment.

However, you could try to export to .fbx. I tried exporting your object to .fbx, for the reimporting to blender. Then the texture was applied correctly. ENTiTi has support for .fbx, so it should be worth a try

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/io_obj.html

Answer (score 0):

obj format do not export the texture applied to the model, it should export the materials and texture in an .mtl file. You would need to apply the .mtl file to your .obj inside your development environment.